# Returning values from an HTML Table to JSON format using HTMLtoJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using the jQuery package [HTMLtoJSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/table-to-json) to convert values from an HTML table to json format. The problem I am encountering is that I am unable to grab the actual  input value using any of the documented options. the json returns what should be between the "<\td>" which in this case is a key value pair example "measured depth":"" and I am looking for something like "Measured Depth":"339"

**Javascript**

```
  <script language='Javascript'>
   function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('Table').deleteRow(i);
}


   function addRow(row)
{
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var tr = document.getElementById('Table').insertRow(i+1);
    tr.innerHTML = row.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
    tr.children[0].innerHTML = tr.parentNode.querySelectorALL("tr").length-1;
} 

 $('#convert-table').click(function()
 {
    var table = $('#Table').tableToJSON(
        {
            onlyColumns:[0,1,2],
            textDataOverride:'text-override'
        });
    console.log(table);
    alert(JSON.stringify(table));
 });


 </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/jquerytabletohtml/jquery.tabletojson.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
  <input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>

  <h1>This is a test for Directional Surveys</h1>
    <div id="tablediv">
        <table id="Table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Measured Depth</b></td>
                <td><b>Inclination</b></td>
                <td><b>Azimuth</b></td>
                <td><b>Delete?</b></td>
                <td><b>Add Row?</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input size=25 type="text" id="Measured Depth0[]" contenteditable="true" value='339'></td>
                <td><input size=25 type="text" id="Inclination0[]" contenteditable='true' value='0.540000021'></td>
                <td><input size=25 type="text" id="Azimuth0[]" contenteditable='true' value='310.7200012'></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="delbutton0" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="addmorebutton0" value="Add Row Below" onclick="addRow(this)"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  <button id="convert-table">Convert!</button>
  <p><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' /></p></form>

  <script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing wildly that a function called `tableToJSON` already creates JSON, and is a string, so it doesn't need you to do `JSON.stringify` once more

Comment: @adeneo One might think so, but actually it's not. It returns normal object, I guess author like many people confuses what JSON means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement extractor function:

```
var table = $('#Table').tableToJSON({
  onlyColumns: [0,1,2],
  textDataOverride: 'text-override',
  extractor: function(cellIndex, $cell) {
    return $cell.find('input').val();
  }
});
```

Comment: great I didn't fully understand that, I appreciate your help